# Oracle - Join 2 tables by date where one is daily and one is monthly

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Suppose I have 2 tables in my oracle database - one with monthly data, the other with daily data with columns, for example, as follows:

**TblMonthlyData:**

```
MonMatchingCol:   MonDateCol:    MonCol3:     MonCol4:
a                 01-31-2014     MonVal3a     MonVal4a
b                 01-31-2014     MonVal3b     MonVal4b
a                 12-31-2013     MonVal3c     MonVal4c
b                 12-31-2013     MonVal3d     MonVal4d
a                 11-30-2013     MonVal3e     MonVal4e
b                 11-30-2013     MonVal3f     MonVal4f
```

**TblDailyData:**

```
DlyMatchingCol   DlyDateCol    DlyCol3    DlyCol4
a                01-14-2014    DlyVal3a   DlyVal4a 
b                01-14-2014    DlyVal3b   DlyVal4b 
a                01-15-2014    DlyVal3c   DlyVal4c 
b                01-15-2014    DlyVal3d   DlyVal4d 
a                01-16-2014    DlyVal3e   DlyVal4e 
b                01-16-2014    DlyVal3f   DlyVal4f 
 ...
a                02-01-2014    DlyVal3g   DlyVal4g 
b                02-01-2014    DlyVal3h   DlyVal4h 
a                02-02-2014    DlyVal3i   DlyVal4i 
b                02-02-2014    DlyVal3j   DlyVal4j
```

And I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
  Daily.DlyDateCol, Daily.DlyMatchingCol, Daily.DlyCol3, Daily.DlyCol4, Monthly.MonCol3, Monthly.MonCol4
FROM 
  TblDailyData Daily, 
  TblMonthlyData Monthly
WHERE
    Daily.DlyDateCol = '01-14-2014'
  AND
    Monthly.MonDateCol = (SELECT MAX(MonDateCol) 
                          FROM TblMonthlyData 
                          WHERE TblMonthlyData.MonDateCol <= '01-14-2014')
  AND
    Daily.DlyMatchingCol = Monthly.MonMatchingCol
```

---

Basically, I have daily data in my daily table and monthly data in my monthly table and they have a column to link the two and I want to get the most recent monthly data up-till that date we're pulling from the daily table.

So, the result of this query would be:

```
DlyDateCol:   DlyMatchingCol:   DlyCol3:   DlyCol4:   MonCol3:   MonCol4:
01-14-2014    a                 DlyVal3a   DlyVal4a   MonVal3c   MonVal4c     
01-14-2014    b                 DlyVal3b   DlyVal4b   MonVal3d   MonVal4d
```

---

Now, this query works great, but now I need to expand it such that I can pull the data for multiple days at a time (so no longer just for `01-14-2014`, but now for, say, `01-15-2014 to 02-10-2014`)?

The result of that query would look as follows:

```
DlyDateCol:   DlyMatchingCol:   DlyCol3:   DlyCol4:   MonCol3:   MonCol4:
01-15-2014    a                 DlyVal3c   DlyVal4c   MonVal3c   MonVal4c     
01-15-2014    b                 DlyVal3d   DlyVal4d   MonVal3d   MonVal4d     
01-16-2014    a                 DlyVal3e   DlyVal4e   MonVal3c   MonVal4c     
01-16-2014    b                 DlyVal3f   DlyVal4f   MonVal3d   MonVal4d     
...
02-01-2014    a                 DlyVal3g   DlyVal4g   MonVal3a   MonVal4a     
02-01-2014    b                 DlyVal3h   DlyVal4h   MonVal3b   MonVal4b     
02-02-2014    a                 DlyVal3i   DlyVal4i   MonVal3a   MonVal4a     
02-02-2014    b                 DlyVal3j   DlyVal4j   MonVal3b   MonVal4b     
...
```

---

So, basically, the daily data would change every day, but the monthly data will change as the months change.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results?

Comment: If you have the condition `Daily.DlyMatchingCol = Monthly.MonMatchingCol`, why do you need the subquery choosing a value of `Monthly.MonDateCol`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I added in fake sample data - I apologize for not doing it before, it was just a lot to type and I had hoped I explained myself well... I hope this makes sense now....

Comment: Basically, I want to get daily data from the daily table and monthly data will repeat itself for each day up until a new month presents itself in the monthly table...

Comment: SQL Fiddle above (using your example via the with clause) is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/25284/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After MUCH playing around, I came up with a solution that worked great - Putting this up here in case anyone else has a similar issue:

```
SELECT 
  Daily.DlyDateCol, Daily.DlyMatchingCol, Daily.DlyCol3, Daily.DlyCol4, Monthly.MonCol3, Monthly.MonCol4
FROM 
  TblDailyData Daily, 
  TblMonthlyData Monthly
WHERE
    Daily.DlyDateCol BETWEEN '01-15-2014' AND '02-10-2014'
  AND
    Monthly.MonDateCol = (SELECT MAX(MonDateCol) 
                          FROM TblMonthlyData 
                          WHERE MonDateCol <= Daily.DlyDateCol)
  AND
    Daily.DlyMatchingCol = Monthly.MonMatchingCol
```

The whole real trick here was simply putting in the `MonDateCol <= Daily.DlyDateCol` - that made them relative to each other on each row (as I wanted) and so the dates flowed through correctly.

I hope that makes sense and thanks again for all your help!!!!

Comment: Didn't see this before I responded :/ Looks like that would work also. When I wrote it originally I didn't see that the monthly date columns was the end of the month preceding that on your daily table. I thought 1/15 and 1/16 etc. would roll up to a row on the monthly table of 1/31 (since they are in January).

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead --

SQL Fiddle (updated 2/16/14) here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/25423/0

```
select d.*, m.mondatecol, m.moncol3, m.moncol4
  from tbldailydata d
  join tblmonthlydata m
    on d.dlymatchingcol = m.monmatchingcol
 where m.mondatecol =
       (select max(x.mondatecol)
          from tblmonthlydata x
         where add_months(to_date(d.dlydatecol, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), -1) <=
               to_date(x.mondatecol, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
           and m.monmatchingcol = x.monmatchingcol)
   and d.dlydatecol between '01-15-2014' and '02-10-2014'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for putting up this solution and I apologize for the lack of sample data. But I feel I simply expressed myself wrong. I've now updated the question with sample data - Basically, I want to get daily data from the daily table and monthly data will repeat itself for each day up until a new month presents itself in the monthly table - I **HOPE** that makes sense now!!

Comment: I think I get it, I just made 2 edits, make sure it's the last one that you try, I forgot a join in the subquery. I'll try it in sqlfiddle when I can but figured I'd give it to you to test in case you get to it faster.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for your work on this ShWiVeL - The SQL Fiddle you posted seems to be pulling in only 1/31 data from the monthly, though,  for both months whereas it should be pulling in 12/31 for the January results.... Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry John I actually added the mondatecol when I wrote it to check on that but must have glazed over that fact, and I was away for a couple days. I changed the subquery used to get the mondatecol and it looks to be getting 12/31 and 1/31 where needed. I updated the sql fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/25423/0   Hope this works for you.